# Trying to figure out what's wrong with this code

Tags: ruby

I can't come up with a solution.

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    @other_name
    print "Hi #{@other_name}, my name is #{@name}"
  end
end

kit = Person.new("Tom", "Jerry")
kit.greet
```

I would appreciate a helping hand.

Comment: This could do with a clear problem statement, otherwise it will just get lost in the system, no use to anyone else. The title needs to refer to the problem you need to solve in some way, and you need to explain what you are trying to do more than just show non-working code. As it stands, this is just a personal "please debug my code and help me with my assignment" with no long-term value to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a decision:

Do you want to provide both names when initializing the `Person`:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name, other)
    @name = name
    @other = other
  end

  def greet
    puts "Hi #{@other}, my name is #{@name}"
  end
end

kit = Person.new("Tom", "Jerry")
kit.greet
#=> Hi Jerry, my name is Tom
```

Or do you want to provide the second name when calling the `greet` method:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other)
    puts "Hi #{other}, my name is #{@name}"
  end
end

kit = Person.new("Tom")
kit.greet("Jerry")
#=> Hi Jerry, my name is Tom
```

Answer (score 0):

In the initialize method, you should take in two parameters, because you are calling it with two. You were declaring the `@other_name` variable inside the `greet` function instead of the `initialize` one.

This will work.

```
class Person 
  def initialize(name, other_name) 
    @name = name
    @other_name = other_name
  end

  def greet 
    print "Hi #{@other_name}, my name is #{@name}" 
  end 
end

kit = Person.new("Tom", "Jerry") 
kit.greet
```

https://repl.it/C5wn

Comment: I find this interesting because I tried that and it didn't work. It says, " 'initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (Argument Error) from 'new' from'

Comment: Did you click on the link and then click run. Because it will 100% work that way

Comment: Yes I did & it ran perfectly. Maybe this site i'm on called, "Codewars" want me do it differently

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing your code like this:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(person)
    puts "Hi #{person.name}, my name is #{name}"
  end
end

tom = Person.new("Tom")
jer = Person.new("Jerry")

tom.greet(jer) #=> Hi Jerry, my name is Tom.
```

This way you actually have another person as an object instead of just a name.

Comment: This is a sensible object model, but it is entirely unclear whether it fits with OP's goals, because the OP has not actually stated what they are.